# Correct put operation to work well in concurrent env?

Tags: java, concurrency

Will that work properly (no race conditions) in concurrent environment?

This is kind of "key autoincrement" feature implementation..

```
private final AtomicInteger atomic = new AtomicInteger(0);
private Map<Long, Integer> hashmap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

void put(String value) {
   hashmap.put(atomic.getAndIncrement(), Integer.valueOf(value));
}
```

I guess not, because `Integer.valueOf` isn't synchronized.. 
Thanks!

Comment: Define "work properly". What do you worry might happen?

Comment: @AndyTurner I meant there will be no race conditions... 
one thread entered into `valueOf` method and parsing an integer, whilst the other one is also entered to the same place... will that be the race condition? 
Since there is no external synchronization, it can be anything, right?

Comment: @Developer87 valueOf is a pure function, and it doesn't hold state. Thus it is by definition thread-safe.

Comment: @Developer87 yes, absolutely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to *synchronize* here

```
Integer.valueOf(value)
```

The `value` argument is a `String` and that means it is *copied* (not really, but consider it to be so).
A `String` is also **immutable**.

`valueOf` is a pure function which doesn't hold a state. Thus, it is by definition thread-safe.
Looking at this small snippet, your code seems fine.